# Finding the distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Question: Let $X$ be real valued random variable with continuous distribution
function $F$. Find the distribution of $U := F(X).$

My idea/attempt: For any  $a \in (0,1)$ there exists $b \in \mathbb R$ sucht that $ F(b) = a$, by continuity of
$F$. Moreover, $a \in (0, 1)$ there is a smallest $b_0 \in \mathbb R$ and a largest $b_1\in \mathbb R$ with
$$F(b_{0}) = a = F(b_{1}).$$
Also, I suspect that we are dealing with a uniform distribution.

---

But I'm not sure how to really write the solution down. Help would really be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why did you remove the question? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be continuous and have CDF, $F$:

$$F(x) = \mathbf P[X \leq x],$$

and the *psuedo-inverse* of $F$ to be

$$F^{-1}(y) = \inf \{ x | F(x) \geq y\}.$$

When $F$ is invertible then $F^{-1}$ is the inverse, but this function exists for all distributions $X$ whilst in general the inverse does not.

Now, letting $U = F(X)$, we can calculate the CDF of $U$ as

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf P[ U \leq u] &= \mathbf P[ F(X) \leq u] \\
& = \mathbf P[ F^{-1} (F(X)) \leq F^{-1}(u)]\\
& = \mathbf P[X \leq F^{-1}(u)] \\
& = F (F^{-1}(u)) \\
& = u 
\end{align}
$$

which is to say that $U$ is uniformly distributed.